# How to create a databricks workspace level service principal using terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, databricks

After some time lost in the docs I'm struggling to figure it out.  I can [create a service principal](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/resources/service_principal) like so:

```
resource "databricks_service_principal" "sp" {
  provider = databricks.workspace

  display_name          = "My service principle"
  databricks_sql_access = true
}
```

There doesn't seem to be a way to output the secret.  Databricks provider does have a [service_principal_secret](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/resources/service_principal_secret), but it is for account level only.

In the account console I can seem to do it.  [oauth secret docs](https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/auth/oauth-m2m.html#step-3-create-an-oauth-secret-for-a-service-principal)

[image]

I tried looking through the docs, and through code completion, to find an output for the secret.

Comment: Does this help: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/resources/service_principal_secret?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, since I'm creating a workspace level service principal, but that resource is for account level only. (I had a formatting error in my question or it would have been clear, it's fixed now)